# Problem with NavArgs in my fragments android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I have problem with NavArgs. I have a fragment A, B, C. From fragment A to fragment B, I pass a field from the Parcelable object, let's call it **currentState**. Then I get into fragment B and pass another field from another Parcelable object, let it be **city** and I get into fragment C. And this is where the strange thing begins. If I navigate from fragment C to fragment B via `findNavController().navigate(action_fragment_c_to_fragment_b)`, then a NullPointerException on my `getArgs()` is thrown, but if I just use `activity?.onBackPressed()`, then the error does not come out. What could be the problem? The error screen and some code are attached below.

```
// Fragment A
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
    android:name=".....FragmentA"
    android:label="...">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment_a_to_fragment_b"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
</fragment>

//Fragment B
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
    android:name=".....FragmentB"
    android:label="...">

    <argument
        android:name="currentState"
        app:argType="..." />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment_b_to_fragment_c"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentC" />
</fragment>

//Fragment C
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
    android:name=".....FragmentC"
    android:label="...">

    <argument
        android:name="city"
        app:argType="..." />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment_c_to_fragment_b"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
</fragment>
```

Code from Fragment B:

```
private val args by navArgs<BFragmentArgs>()
private var reference: String? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    ...
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    getArgs()
}

private fun getArgs() {
    reference = args.currentState.name
}
```

[image]
[image]

P.S.: on a screenshot you can see AttractionFragmentArgs, in my case it is BFragmentArgs

Comment: Can you please post the exception as a text not image

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `findNavController().navigate(action_fragment_c_to_fragment_b)` instead of using `findNavController().popBackStack()` if you're trying to pop back to B?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, the reason is that in the future I plan to pass a new argument from fragment C to fragment B via FragmentDirections and will use findNavController().navigate(action)

Comment: That's not how you are supposed to [return a result to a previous destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result). Is there a reason you aren't doing that?

Comment: I can simulate this with running ads shell am kill app.package.name

Answer (score -1):

> `IllegalArgumentException required argument "currentState" is missing and does not have defaultValue`

This means that the argument named `currentState` misses a default value in the navGraph.

As your arg type is a data class that is definitely a parcelable or serializable, then [as per documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types), the default value can only be null:

> Supports a default value of "@null". Does not support other default values.

So, you can set its default value to `null`:

```
<argument
    android:name="currentState"
    app:nullable="true"
    android:defaultValue="@null"        
    app:argType="..." />
```

Comment: oh, I forgot to say that in fragment A I have a RecyclerView and an adapter, in the `onBindViewHolder()` function I use `AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment(getItem(position))` and if I set `app:nullable="true"` and `android:defaultValue="@null"` the error ***Too many arguments for public open fun actionAFragmentToBFragment()*** appears

Comment: @SECTOR can you tell what is the type set in `app:argType`

Comment: this is a data class that contains string variables: name, image, terrain. For example, one of them (specified in the class constructor): `var name: String = ""`

Comment: @SECTOR please try this instead ..Not sure as can't test it out right now `findNavController().navigate(AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment().setCurrentState(getItem(position))`

Comment: Yes, this method partially solves the problem, but the problem itself has not disappeared. I did an interesting test. In fragment B I wrote `Log.d(args.currentState.name)` and revealed that when using findNavController, the argument is empty and ***NullPointerException*** crashes, and when using `onBackPressed()` or `popBackStack()`, the argument is not empty and is output to Logcat

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.   I have 4 args that are created in the Navcomponent and using safe args.  3 of 4 are Classes that are Parcelized.  If you background the app then kill is with add shell am kill com.android.appname then when you go back and foreground it fails to reconstitute and crashes with invocation error.  If I add the defaultValue = @null I get the too many arguments.  I can fix it with ignore the args if savedInstanceState is not null but I can't grab the Parcelables that are my args from a Bundle